# Ошибка в set_tensor на Python (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Код:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import librosa

def preprocess_audio(audio_file_path, sample_rate=16000, target_length=17920):
    audio, _ = librosa.load(audio_file_path, sr=sample_rate, mono=True)
    mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(audio, sr=sample_rate)

    length_diff = target_length - mel_spectrogram.shape[1]

    if length_diff > 0:
        mel_spectrogram = np.pad(mel_spectrogram, ((0, 0), (0, length_diff)), mode='constant')
    elif length_diff < 0:
        mel_spectrogram = mel_spectrogram[:, :target_length]

    mel_spectrogram = mel_spectrogram.astype(np.float32)
    return mel_spectrogram

def load_model(model_path):
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    return interpreter, input_details, output_details

def transcribe_notes(audio_file_path, tflite_model_path):
    interpreter, input_details, output_details = load_model(tflite_model_path)

    mel_spectrogram = preprocess_audio(audio_file_path)

    input_data = mel_spectrogram.reshape(1, -1)
    print("1===============================1")
    print(interpreter.get_input_details())
    print("1===============================1")
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()
    transcription = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

    return transcription

def main():
    audio_file_path = "audio.wav"

    tflite_model_path = "onsets_frames_wavinput.tflite"

    notes = transcribe_notes(audio_file_path, tflite_model_path)
    print("Notes transcription:")
    print(notes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод (проблема):

```
1===============================1
[{'name': 'Placeholder', 'index': 16, 'shape': array([17920]), 'shape_signature': array([17920]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 
0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
1===============================1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Master/Desktop/py/C15.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Master/Desktop/py/C15.py", line 46, in main
    notes = transcribe_notes(audio_file_path, tflite_model_path)
  File "c:/Users/Master/Desktop/py/C15.py", line 35, in transcribe_notes
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
  File "C:\Users\Master\miniconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\interpreter.py", line 697, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 2 but expected 1 for input 16.
```

Немного не понимаю, как нужно переписать код, чтобы избежать данной ошибки и из-за чего она.
Модель (onsets_frames_wavinput.tflite) скачал отсюда: https://github.com/magenta/magenta/blob/main/magenta/models/onsets_frames_transcription/realtime/README.md
Возможно дело в модели.